# PDFsharp - Use private font

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, pdfsharp

I am currently working on a little piece of code which generates a PDF file. To follow the design specification, I need to use the 'Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold' font. As where the program will run, there is no font installation available I need to use it as a private font.

It does not work. I tried different family names and such, but I keep failing over and over...

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(fontUri);
XPrivateFontCollection.Global.AddFont(data, "#Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold");
```

And when I want to use the font.

```
XFont big = new XFont("Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold", 36, XFontStyle.Regular);
```

But this keeps failing over and over again. I have imported the file into my project, it is a .ttf file. I cannot figure it out.

Is there anyone who knows my issue and maybe knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have some exception thrown?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx

Comment: @activatedgeek: I do not get any exceptions.

Comment: @SamY: Can't use that, working with PdfSharp.. The XGraphics.DrawString method expects an XFont and not a Font.

Comment: have you tried installing the font to the standard windows fonts?

Comment: @SamY: As said in the post, it is not possible to install fonts on the server (they do not want to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you download the PDFsharp source package, you will find a working sample that uses private fonts.
Use this to get started.
See folder "PDFSharp-MigraDocFoundation-1_32\PDFsharp\samples\Samples C#\Based on GDI+\PrivateFonts" after unzipping.

If you can't get it to work with your font, you will at least have an SSCCE which you can submit for testing.

Source code can be found here:
http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases

Or maybe use PDFsharp 1.50 beta from NuGet where you use a FontResolver to work with private fonts.
See sample resolver here:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=8961#p8961

Comment: I downloaded the sourcecode from the link, added PdfSharp in my project using NuGet Package Manager. I also added the both fonts file to my project folder via the Solution Explorer.

When I built the application, it showed me pdf with the text, but not with the specified fonts. Do I need to have a certain version for this example? My current version using is PDFsharp **1.32.3057.0**

Comment: You have to use the WPF build of PDFsharp 1.32. When calling XPrivateFontCollection.Add, write the font name as Windows expects it, prefixed with "./#". When using the fonts, write the font name as Word shows it. When you reference the projects from the source code and not the NuGet packages, then you can step through the PDFsharp source code to see which fonts are registered in the XPrivateFontCollection. Then you can see if "Add()" was successful and which name has to be used with "new XFont()".

Comment: The sample resolver does indeed work. I am going to try the PDF Sharp 1.32 WPF Build with my old code now.

Comment: It could be that you have to write "./#Helvetica Neue" and "Helvetica Neue" instead of "./#Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold" and "Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold". And "#Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold" as given in the question won't work as Windows needs "./#".

Comment: That does not seem to resolve the issue. As said everywhere, I need to use the name as it used in the Windows Font Viewer. So that would be "Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold" (and with the ./# for the family name).

**I fixed the issue**

I forgot the XpdfFontOptions as a parameter while constructing the fonts. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully solved the problem.

I was using the WPF Build instead of the GDI build. Besides that, the Uri's were wrong and the familynames were entered the wrong way.

Comment: I know this post is pretty old, but can you provide the pertinent source code?  I am having a similar issue, and I am not sure what I am missing.  I am working on a desktop application, but I don't know why that would make a significant difference.